# Get the Feature id openlayers5

Tags: openlayers-5

In OL2 feature id's were generated internally. In OL5 this doesn't seem to be the case since the id's are undefined.  Has the internal feature id been removed from OL5? If not what do I need to do to get the id's generated. I am requesting the id via:

feature.getId()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openlayers 5 doesn't generate the feature ID.

You have to set the feature's ID (if necessary) when creating it. Use the `setId` method.
Now by calling `feature.getId()` you will get the feature id.

It must be taken into account that in the same source of the map the id must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

If a geoJson or other source contains feature ids they will be used, otherwise the feature id will be left undefined.  You could generate your own ids if you you need them. 
 If the source contains a mix of features with and without id you will need to ensure  your auto generated ids are unique (e.g. use a prefix).

```
var featureId = 0;
vector.getSource().on('addfeature', function(e){
  featureId++;
  if (!e.feature.getId()) {
    e.feature.setId('auto-gen-'+featureId);
  }
});
```